# java protector, защита от декомпиляции

Tags: java

Какой использовать java protector, чтобы нормально защитить java код от декомпиляции ? 
лучше всего opensource free решения.

Comment: лучшая защита - это писать код так, чтобы его и без протекоров никто не понял))

Comment: нормально  защитить код.......opensource решения........ качественно  и бесплатно? Однако однако..)))

Answer (score 1):

[ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/). Там же [альтернативные](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#alternatives.html) варианты и небольшое их сравнение.

**UPD:** Но, нужно понимать, что никакой обфускатор не защитит Ваш код на 100%. Он, лишь, сможет усложнить процесс декомпиляции и увеличить потраченное на это время.